# Permission denied when writing to /tmp directory when using su command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am running following command as root user -

```
su - testuser -c 'id >/tmp/test.txt'
```

I expect to see `/tmp/test.txt` being created with the id details of the testuser account but I get error- `-bash: /tmp/test.txt: Permission denied`

I've verified that /tmp is world writable

How do I debug this?

Note that testuser has `/bin/bash` as shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes. Your user's bash will take care of redirection.

In your previous attempts, testuser created /tmp/test.txt. /tmp has the *sticky bit* enabled, which prevents you from removing testuser's /tmp/test.txt. You may remove it as root or using sudo.

Comment: I just updated my question, now I am running into another issue.

Comment: but yea, removing the quote seems to have fixed issue. thanks!